# Connecting with public ip in RMI

Tags: java, ip, rmi

I had written a RMI client/server program in which  Server simply reads properties from file and give it to the client. The server and client programs both reside on my machine. Sample code for server is

```
public class DirectoryStructure {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "local ip");
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    DirectoryOperations directoryOperations;
    try {
        directoryOperations = new DirectoryOperations();

        Naming.rebind("rmi://local ip/ABC", directoryOperations);

        directoryOperations.addAddess("name",
                "addeess");
        System.out.println("Directory Server is ready.");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As you can see in the rebind method when i pass my **local ip**  i am able to start the server successfully.When i replace this local ip with my machine's **public ip** i am not able to connect i get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`. Can anyone suggest how to start server using public ip ?

Answer (score 0):

That just means you haven't forwarded the necessary port (1099) from your public IP router to your RMI host inside the LAN.

If you want clients to connect via the public IP address, you should also set `java.rmi.server.hostname` to the public IP address.

But it doesn't really make sense to use any IP address other than `"localhost"` in a `Naming.bind()/rebind()/unbind()` call, as the Registry you're talking to for those purposes must be running in the localhost anyway. It only makes sense for the client to use the public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @EJP,

You should call register code (Naming.rebind()) on the server machine with localhost.

To access the remote objects, use Naming.lookup(), this is where your client tries to access to access the rmi server (whether local/over internet)

If you use public IP for the look up, the request will go from your gateway(your router) and inturn to the Server's accesspoint,(its router, that's handling the incoming public requests). As EJP mentioned, the router should route that request to the correct machine.